# using R How to remove all words after a specific character in

Tags: r, stringr

I have a column in tbl_df titled "Search" and would like to remove all characters to the right of the question mark "?"

Example

```r
Atlanta?adfjladsfjf
Georgia?fdfdfjflajf
LosAngeles?adlfdkfd
```

Desired output

```r
Atlanta
Georgia 
Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
tbl_df$Search <- sub("\\?.*", "", tbl_df$Search)
```

---

If it needs to be applied in more than one column, use `lapply` from `base R`

```
nm1 <- names(tbl_df)[1:2] # // applying for first two columns
tbl_df[nm1] <- lapply(tbl_df[nm1], sub, pattern = "\\?.*", replacement  = "")
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tbl_df <- tbl_df %>%
         mutate(across(all_of(nm1), str_remove, pattern = "\\?.*"))
```

Comment: I have to run the same command over 10 more "search" columns. Is there a way to write a for loop or function where I don't have to copy and past the same code over and over?

Comment: @TylerWitt You can just do `tbl_df[yourcolnms] <- lapply(tbl_df[yourcolnms], function(x) sub("\\?.*", "", x))`  The `yourcolnms` can be column names or just numeric index

Answer (score 1):

a alternative with rebus and stringr:

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

td <- c("Atlanta?adfjladsfjf","Georgia?fdfdfjflajf","LosAngeles?adlfdkfd")

p <- START %R% capture(one_or_more(ALPHA)) %R% "?"

stringr::str_extract(td, p)

[1] "Atlanta"    "Georgia"    "LosAngeles"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using `sub` but with pattern `"(.*)\\?.*"`

```
> sub("(.*)\\?.*","\\1",s)
[1] "Atlanta"    "Georgia"    "LosAngeles"
```

where the part before reaching `"?"` is kept.

**Data**

```
s <- c("Atlanta?adfjladsfjf","Georgia?fdfdfjflajf","LosAngeles?adlfdkfd")
```